# Coding with tools only downloadable in Microsoft Store

Tags: java, visual-studio

My laptop is broken and is at the service right now so I got a borrowed laptop from school. Unfortunately we have no administrator rights on these laptops and a lot of stuff is limited by the administrator. The only way to download tools/applications is through the Microsoft Store. (It is not in s-mode or something, really restricted.) So I want to program and write projects in Java. Normally I use IntelliJ, but that was not in the MS store. I downloaded Visual Studio but am unable to download the JDK.

My question to you: Is it at all possible to create and run java projects with Microsoft Store as the only download store? (Windows 10 Enterprise 21H1)

Thanks in advance!

- Tried visual studio but can not run because JDK is missing
- Tried a browser IDE, but they work terrible and not really suitable for writing projects

Comment: If you found my answer helpful, it would  be greatly appropriated if you selected it as the correct answer for your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio Code might be an option if it works https://apps.microsoft.com/store/detail/visual-studio-code/XP9KHM4BK9FZ7Q, but your best bet would be the following:

You can use an online tool called GitHub Codespaces: https://github.com/features/codespaces

Codespaces runs a VSCode environment in your browser. You will run a java project just as you would if you where using VSCode. How to use GitHub Dev https://github.com/github/dev

Check out this link if you want to know more about advanced use of Java in a Codespace: https://docs.github.com/en/codespaces/setting-up-your-project-for-codespaces/adding-a-dev-container-configuration/setting-up-your-java-project-for-codespaces